# Docker-compose diesel migration run

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I want to deploy my rust project, which is using ffmpeg, mysql(diesel.rs) and the framework actix-web, to truenas scale. Thats why i created a docker container.

This is the Dockerfile. Mysql isnt working. How can I install mysql.

```
FROM rust:latest


# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    pkg-config \
    libssl-dev \
    ffmpeg \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN diesel migration run
```

Error:

```
 > [ 7/10] RUN diesel migration run:                                                                                                     
#0 0.199 Could not connect to database via `mysql://root:root@localhost/movies`: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I added a docker compose. The init file contains "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS movies"
Edit:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    # NOTE: use of "mysql_native_password" is not recommended: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html#upgrade-caching-sha2-password
    # (this is just an example, not intended to be a production configuration)
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password --init-file init.sql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
  
  backend:
    depends_on:
      - db
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports: 
      - 8080:8080
```

Comment: When you say "MySQL isn't working", what actually happens?  A container only runs a single process and a Dockerfile runs before any container in particular starts, so you can never `RUN mysql` in a Dockerfile; you almost always need to run the database in a separate container.

Comment: The service isnt running.

Comment: how can i create an image that has one container for the mysql and one for the project?

Answer (score 0):

**Don't use two services in one container**. it's possible to run several processes in container, but it's bad practice. In your example you have not mysql service running, because for this your need systemd running insude container( this is another big story:) ).

Use docker-compose with 2 services: your app and mysql. Communicate each other by service name(this is compose feature). How to use docker-compose watch study video or read docs. Here template for your app:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  app:
  build:
    context: <path to dir with Dockerfile>
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  #Add another options for your app: ports, mount files and variables

  db:
    image: mysql
    # NOTE: use of "mysql_native_password" is not recommended: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html#upgrade-caching-sha2-password
    # (this is just an example, not intended to be a production configuration)
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

Comment: how can the 2 services interact when building? I want to use `diesel migration run` in the backend service. This will create the databases.

Comment: All services in compose communicate by service name and port inside container(as example 5432 for pgsql). You can run one service after another. Use `depends_on`  Run first service with migrations and another start only after migration service finished. As example [Grafana OnCall](https://github.com/grafana/oncall/blob/dev/docker-compose.yml), first start redis and db_migrations, then start main service (enginx + celery).